# Ethernet LAN disconnects after turning off kitchen tubelight or fan

Tags: electrical, ethernet

Whenever my kitchen tube light or fan is turned off or on my Ethernet LAN disconnects. How could they interfere with the the Ethernet? My Laptop is connected only to LAN Ethernet cable

What could cause this to disconnect?

Comment: What kind of LAN is it... ethernet, Wifi, what frequencies your WiFi is using, make/model of router, and make/model of PC.   Where is the router and cable/DSL modem plugged in relative to the light, i.e. does turning off the circuit breaker for one turn off the other?  What kind of light is it, what's a tube light, how old is the fixture?  Have you changed any parts and did that help?

Comment: It is Ethernet LAN.I replaced tube light and now it's fine .Fan is very old and that causes  still same issue as  mentioned above

Comment: Is your router or access point plugged into a switched outlet?

Comment: No. only Ethernet LAN wire coming from local internet provider

Answer (score 1):

> Ethernet LAN wire coming from local internet provider

Your profile says you're in India. It also sounds like your ISP has an Ethernet wire that runs into your dwelling (I suspect this is an apartment). I further suspect they ran the cheaper Cat 5e inside the building.

Fluorescent lighting produces a fair amount of electromagnetic interference. My bet is that the Ethernet parallels either the light fixture or the electrical wiring in general (I could easily see the latter being done to save costs by cutting corners).

Unfortunately, since you didn't run the wiring yourself, there's no easy fixes here. If you had run them, I would make sure you keep the Ethernet away from the electrical. I would also run Cat 6, since it affords better shielding. Putting the wire inside conduit would also offer better shielding.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming wifi, since you didn't say where the disconnect occurs... Sounds like they're producing radio noise when turned off -- not uncommon -- snd that your wifi drivers or hardware or xdrivers or applications are much worse than most at retrying after packets wdre garbled.

Comment: Shouldnt LAN imply Ethernet? I'm pretty sure WiFi is known as wLAN.

Comment: @hmscelestia: LAN is local area network, generic. WLAN is wireless LAN, which is a subcategory of LAN. Wired LAN is not always Ethernet (USB is implemented as a LAN), wireless is not always WiFi (ZigBee, Bluetooth, etc). Yes, your usage is the most common case, but as a techie I can't make that assumption.

Comment: Honestly, in my experience when working with people I find that its best to make those assumptions, as those with the skill to implement LANs other than Ethernet or WiFi normally specify which type they're using if they aren't using one of the common types.

Comment: LAN is any local area network--typically a layer 2 broadcast domain. It can be implemented using a number of technologies and although the world has largely settled on Ethernet now, just a few years ago you could have had a LAN on Ethernet, token ring, FDDI, HDLC, AppleTalk and yes, wireless (and more). You can't really call devices on a wireless network a WLAN unless the wireless network is on a separate VLAN, and technically wireless Ethernet is the purest form we still use because it is still CSMA/CD and not switched. LAN is really any part of the network inside your firewall.  Peace.  :)

Comment: Also, the OP specifically said the laptop is plugged in with a cable, so not wireless.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before with leased modems from the broadband company.  The modem lacks appropriate filters to keep out noises, or its existing filters aren't cutting it.   Try relocating network hardware to different circuit, and/or replacing fan.